# Angular Dynamic reference of element and how to use it in component

Tags: angular

In our project, we have a ngFor loop parsing some users. For each user, I set in html, using ngx-bootstrap, a modal containing "more users information". Then, on the user row, we have a button which have to call the user specific modal.

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of usersList">
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
    <span>
        <a (click)="moreDetailsModal.show()">Edit/More Detail</a>
    <span>

    <div bsModal #additionalInformationModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade">
        <h2>Details - {{ user.name }}</h2>
        <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="userDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="editUserDetails();">
            User ZIP Code: <input type="text" name="zip" value="{{ user.zip }}">

            <button type="submit">Edit User</button>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

My questions are:

- Do I have to set `#additionalInformationModal` reference dyanmically and with a different ID (using for example `user.id`) or Angular will be sufficiently smart to call the proper user specific modal when clicking on `Edit/More Details` button? It seems to work as expected but I want to know if its due to a lucky mistake or Angular normal behavior.

  - If I have to use this reference in my Typescript component, how to retrieve a specific user one using @viewChild ? Since all references have the same name. For example, in case I need to call `moreDetailsModal.show()` from the typscript part.
  - If I have to set reference to be a dynamic one, how to achieve the dynamic naming? And how to use it in both HTML and TS part of my component?
- Will Angular be able to create all subsequent data driven forms since they have all the same name: `userDetailsForm`

Thanks for your explainations!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to set #additionalInformationModal reference dynamically and
>   with a different ID...

Yes template reference should be unique.
best way to do this to use array or object

1. Define object or array in component

   public RefVarable: {} = {};
2. In *ngFor loop use index

   *ngFor="let user of usersList; let i = index;"
3. use RefVarable[i] to reference the modal

> If I have to use this reference in my Typescript component, how to
>   retrieve a specific user one using @viewChild ? Since all references
>   have the same name...

As I told before reference variables should be unique.

> If I have to use this reference in my Typescript component, how to
>   retrieve a specific user one using @viewChild...

&

> If I have to set reference to be a dynamic one, how to achieve the
>   dynamic naming...

1. use array or object.
2. use index or userId as key of objects to reference them.

> Will Angular be able to create all subsequent data driven forms since
>   they have all the same name: userDetailsForm

Use same technique for forms.